# How to run MEAN stack in docker on local environment?

Tags: javascript, docker, mean-stack, lerna

I'm new to MEAN projects and I have a new project I've successfully cloned and need to get running locally to develop against. I have no idea where to start.

It has things like docker, lerna, yarn, etc. How can I get this working on my local dev machine? I have PC and Mac resources as well as resources like Azure and AWS (Cloud9).

### Update

I had to do things like the following to get it up and running. Now, this took a few minutes to run. My question now is, will I have to stop and start this process each time I make a change (the npm run dev part, I mean)?

```
npm -v
nvm ls
nvm install 8.9.4
node -v
nvm alias default 8.9.4

ssh-keygen
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

git clone <repo>

copy .env.dev
copy .env.local

Database connection strings

npm install -g lerna yarn pm2

sudo pip install docker-compose

export NPM_TOKEN=00000000-0000-0000-000-00000000000
echo $NPM_TOKEN
lerna bootstrap


npm run dev
```

Comment: cloned from where?

Comment: Share repository URL from where you cloned project?

Comment: Sorry, client's intellectual property. I know that hurts my chances of getting help. Possibly only hope is general guidance around JacaScript projects and best practices

Comment: For example, generally when cloning a project I'm used to doing npm install and then npm start, but I think this project is going to be a little more complex than that.

Comment: try running it with `node app.js` or `node <file_name_you_want_to_run.js>`

Comment: Can you share your package.json file? You can do this without needing to refresh every time.

Comment: Which one? There are many of them.